# Using combination of "head" and "tail" to display middle line of the file in Unix

Tags: unix, tail, unix-head

If I have a file name `myownfile.txt` which contains 3 lines of text.

```
foo
hello world
bar
```

I want to display the line in the middle which is `hello world` by using `head` and `tail` command only.

Comment: What if the file has more than 3 lines???

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
head -2 myownfile | tail -1
```

should do what you want

Comment: Thank you it does work! can you give a little bit of explaination please about the part where head says -2 means start from line 2? and tail -1 also start from line 2 from bottom?

Comment: `head -2` gets the first **two** lines of the file. This output is piped to `tail -1` which gets the last **one** line of the _piped output_ (this might be somewhere in the middle of the file).

Answer (score 5):

`head -2` displays first 2 lines of a file

```
$ head -2 myownfile.txt
foo
hello world
```

`tail -1` displays last line of a file:

```
$ head -2 myownfile.txt | tail -1
hello world
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the party here, but a more flexible way of doing this would be to use awk rather than using head and tail.

Your command would look like this:

```
awk 'NR==2' myfile.txt
```

> hello world

Answer (score 1):

Try `head -2 | tail -1`. That's the last line (`tail -1`) of the first half + one (`head -2`).

Answer (score 1):

tail -2 myownfile.txt|head -1

it will show the 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a few instances in the past, where someone provided a daring solution to some file handling problem with `sed`. I never really understood how they worked.

Today I had to do some line editing on huge files with just the basic tools and came across this question. Not satisfied by using combinations of `tail` and `head` I decided to find out about the true power of `sed`.

Reading https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html gave me all the information I needed. So I want to share this with anybody else who might stumble upon a similar problem and not know the true power of `sed`:

```sh
sed -n "2 p" myownfile.txt
```

The `-n` option disables all implicit printing, `2` addresses just the second line and `p` prints that specific line to stdout.